# Multiple columns and I want to rearrange these columns based on another column in R or Excel

Tags: r, excel, formatting, data-cleaning, data-processing

[image]

I have data that looks like this. For `R_fighter`, I want `R_fighter` have the fighters that are the winner defined in the winning column.

For example, this is not satisfied for row 5, where Petr Yan won the fight but he is in `B_fighter`. Also, I would need `R_KD` and `B_KD` to be swapped for row 5, and `R_sig_str` and `B_sig_str`. I have many more columns with `R_` and `B_` column attributes, and would need them all swapped as well.

I need all rows with the winner on `B_fighter` switched.

Attached is a sample of my data:

```
R_fighter,B_fighter,R_KD,B_KD,R_SIG_STR.,B_SIG_STR.,win_by,weight,winner

Henry Cejudo,Marlon Moraes,0,0,90 of 171,57 of 119,KO/TKO,UFC Bantamweight Title Bout,Henry Cejudo

Valentina Shevchenko,Jessica Eye,1,0,8 of 11,2 of 12,KO/TKO,UFC Women's Flyweight Title Bout,Valentina Shevchenko

Tony Ferguson,Donald Cerrone,0,0,104 of 200,68 of 185,TKO - Doctor's Stoppage,Lightweight Bout,Tony Ferguson

Jimmie Rivera,Petr Yan,0,2,73 of 192,56 of 189,Decision - Unanimous,Bantamweight Bout,Petr Yan

Tai Tuivasa,Blagoy Ivanov,0,1,64 of 144,73 of 123,Decision - Unanimous,Heavyweight Bout,Blagoy Ivanov

Tatiana Suarez,Nina Ansaroff,0,0,75 of 142,48 of 99,Decision - Unanimous,Women's Strawweight Bout,Tatiana Suarez

Aljamain Sterling,Pedro Munhoz,0,0,174 of 349,105 of 265,Decision - Unanimous,Bantamweight Bout,Aljamain Sterling

Karolina Kowalkiewicz,Alexa Grasso,0,0,90 of 232,148 of 369,Decision - Unanimous,Women's Strawweight Bout,Alexa Grasso

Ricardo Lamas,Calvin Kattar,0,1,12 of 29,22 of 41,KO/TKO,Featherweight Bout,Calvin Kattar

Yan Xiaonan,Angela Hill,0,0,94 of 249,71 of 144,Decision - Unanimous,Women's Strawweight Bout,Yan Xiaonan

Bevon Lewis,Darren Stewart,0,0,31 of 84,30 of 73,Decision - Unanimous,Middleweight Bout,Darren Stewart

Eddie Wineland,Grigorii Popov,2,0,74 of 171,55 of 150,KO/TKO,Bantamweight Bout,Eddie Wineland

Katlyn Chookagian,Joanne Calderwood,0,0,82 of 221,112 of 266,Decision - Unanimous,Women's Flyweight Bout,Katlyn Chookagian
```

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dplyr` package in R which has plenty of functions to reshape data.

In your case you could use something like:

```
library(dplyr)
mydata %>%
 mutate(R_fighter_new = winner,
        B_fighter_new = if_else(R_fighter == winner, B_fighter, R_fighter),
        R_KD_new = if_else(R_fighter == winner, R_KD, B_KD),
        B_KD_new = if_else(R_fighter == winner, B_KD, R_KD)) %>%
 select(R_fighter = R_fighter_new, B_fighter = B_fighter_new, R_KD = R_KD_new, B_KD = B_KD_new, winner)
```

In the last `select` statement you can include all the columns you want in your dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `case_when` in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
mydata %>%
    mutate(R_fighter_new = winner,
    B_fighter_new = case_when(R_fighter == winner ~ B_fighter,TRUE~ R_fighter),
    R_KD_new = case_when(R_fighter == winner~R_KD, TRUE ~ B_KD),
    B_KD_new = case_when(R_fighter == winner ~ B_KD, TRUE ~ R_KD)) %>%
    select(R_fighter = R_fighter_new, B_fighter = B_fighter_new, R_KD = R_KD_new, B_KD = B_KD_new, winner)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this with multiple columns to swap. First, add a match number column for each row. Then, `pivot_longer` so you have a single column for R vs. B. This column would be swapped depending on fighter and winner values. Then, to put back into original wider format, you can use `pivot_wider`. Note that `pivot_wider` will put the "value" in front of output since it contains multiple values (R and B were moved to the end).

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(match_no = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = R_fighter:B_SIG_STR., names_to = c("R_vs_B", ".value"), names_pattern = "(R|B)_(\\w+)") %>%
  mutate(R_vs_B = case_when(R_vs_B == "B" & fighter == winner ~ "R",
                            R_vs_B == "R" & fighter != winner ~ "B",
                            TRUE ~ R_vs_B)) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(match_no, winner, win_by, weight), names_from = R_vs_B, values_from = fighter:SIG_STR)
```